# Is there a way to aggregate multiple Pandas rows into a single row with extra columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for an efficient way to aggregate a Pandas DataFrame based on a column value, where the columns are expanded and named based on the value in another column. This is best explained by an example:

This is my input DataFrame:

```py
  customer device   x   y   z
0     Jack      M   1   2   3
1     Jack      D   4   5   6
2     Jane      M   7   8   9
3     Jane      D  10  11  12
```

And this is the output I want:

```py
  customer  x_M  y_M  z_M  x_D  y_D  z_D
0     Jack    1    2    3    4    5    6
1     Jane    7    8    9   10   11   12
```

As you can see, "aggregation" is possibly a misleading word to use. Rather, the rows are "expanded" into columns that are named based on another column from their respective rows.

In my mind I will have to do some sort of loop - but I was hoping for a more efficient Pandas operation than can do the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `pivot` the dataframe, then join the columns at two levels by `_`:

```py
>>> out=df.pivot('customer', 'device', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> out.columns=['_'.join(c) for c in out]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
          x_D  x_M  y_D  y_M  z_D  z_M
customer                              
Jack        4    1    5    2    6    3
Jane       10    7   11    8   12    9
```

Comment: Scrap my previous comment - this works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Following on your code, we can also reset the index to get the exact format that was asked for:  out.reset_index(inplace=True)